# Can I use C++ templates to generate Unicode/ANSI variants of a function, rather than using the preprocessor?

Tags: c++, windows, templates

We've got a bunch of legacy code that doesn't support Unicode, so a transitional pattern we use in our code is to move the function to a `.inl` file, change `char` to `CHAR_TYPE`, and then wrap it up like this:

```
#define CHAR_TYPE wchar_t
#define STRING_TYPE std::wstring
#define MyFunctionName MyFunctionNameW
#include "MyFunction.inl"

#undef CHAR_TYPE
#define CHAR_TYPE char
#undef STRING_TYPE
#define STRING_TYPE std::string
#undef MyFunctionName
#define MyFunctionName MyFunctionNameA
#include "MyFunction.inl"
```

...where `MyFunction.inl` then defines `MyFunctionName`, using the macros to generate both an 'A' version and a 'W' version.

This is icky, but it's unfortunately necessary until we get all of our code converted to support Unicode.

Is there an alternative way I could do this with templates? I'm thinking that something like the following would be nice:

```
typedef MyFunctionName<wchar_t, std::wstring> MyFunctionNameW
typedef MyFunctionName<char, std::string> MyFunctionNameA
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Windows already provides such macros. Are you talking about non-Win32 APIs?

Comment: I'm talking about functions implemented in our code. We need to convert them to Unicode, piecemeal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roger Pate is entire correct about the interface. You shouldn't bother with A and W suffixes. However, this still leaves the problem of implementation. As you supected, templates are the correct solution. And since you don't need the different names, you can leave out the typedefs. You would just have

`template <typename TSTRING> void MyFunctionName (TSTRING const&);`

Comment: The only thing here is that I think it chould be `typename TCHAR` rather than `typename TSTRING`.

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* I misread the question, thinking you already had A and W functions written which you wanted to call through the same name.  What you have is indeed a situation for which templates are designed, but I won't repeat the correct answer.

Simple overloading works, no need for templates or additional complexity.  The Win32 API uses macros because C doesn't have overloading.

```
inline
void MyFunctionName(std::wstring const& value) { MyFunctionNameW(value); }
inline
void MyFunctionName(std::string const& value) { MyFUnctionNameA(value); }
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all, if the original function signature is something similar to
    char MyFunctionName(int x, float y);

Comment: If the functions only differ in return type, templates won't help either.

Comment: I believe the point here is to avoid duplicating the _bodies_ of `MyFunctionName`.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible, this is basically what std::string and std::wstring do anyway as they are actually typedefs of `std::basic_string<charT,traits,alloc>`.

Comment: In what parallel universe did `std::string` become a function? ;)

Comment: `std::string` has a lot of member functions which are seemingly "widechar-neutral".